# How to remove cell from static UITableView created in Storyboard

Tags: ios, uitableview, storyboard

This should be easy, but I'm having trouble.

I have a static UITableView with a cell that I would like to remove programmatically if it's not needed.

I have a IBOutlet for it

```
IBOutlet UITableViewCell * cell15;
```

And I can remove it by calling

```
cell15.hidden = true;
```

This hides it, but leaves a blank space where the cell used to be and I can't get rid of it.

Perhaps a hack would be to change the height of it to 0?

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath
{
//what would I put here?
}
```

Thanks so much!

Comment: How about `tableView:deleteRowAtIndexPath:`?
Did not try by myself, just a quick way to try

Comment: thanks! how would I go about selecting the row i want to delete?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove a Static Cell from a UITableView designed in StoryBoard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8262270/how-to-remove-a-static-cell-from-a-uitableview-designed-in-storyboard)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can't really deal with this in the datasource since with static tables you don't even implement the datasource methods. The height is the way to go.

Try this:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{ 
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    if (cell == cell15 && cell15ShouldBeHidden) //BOOL saying cell should be hidden
        return 0.0;
    else
        return [super tableView:tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]; 
}
```

**Update**

It appears that, under autolayout, this may not be the best solution. There is an alternative answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18951274/852828) which may help.

Comment: I got a `BAD_ACCESS` in a case like this. Doesn't the TableView ask the height _before_ the cell is instanciated?

Comment: It asks before (in which case the cell will be nil, and fall through to the super) and also during scrolling, I think, and I don't see how you'd get a bad access with this code. You should post a new question, with a link to this answer.

Comment: I also got a `BAD_ACCESS` caused by some kind of infinite loop. I fixed it by not comparing the cell but the index path like so: `if (indexPath.row == 3 && cellShouldBeHidden)`

Comment: Agreed, this will loop and give you BAD_ACCESS, this should not be the accepted answer to this question.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `tableView:willDisplayCell` and `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath` with the cell identifier to show/hide static `tableview` cells, but yo must implement `heightForRowAtIndexPath` referring to `super`, not to `self`. These two methods work fine for me:

```
(void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
if ([cell.reuseIdentifier.description isEqualToString:@"cellCelda1"]) {
    [cell setHidden:YES];
    }
}
```

and

```
(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [super tableView:tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    if ([cell.reuseIdentifier.description isEqualToString:@"cellCelda1"]) {
        return 0;
}
    return cell.frame.size.height;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Depending on how your table is supposed to work, in your data source you can implement `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` to return 0 rows for the section based on your necessary logic.

Updated for your comment:

The section parameter will be populated by iOS when your implementation is called so all you need is a switch to handle the section that has the row you ant removed/hidden. Example below:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    switch(section) {
        case 0:  // first section of your table, change for your situation
             return 0;
        default:
             return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: how do I select the section in code? this is something i'm really having trouble with...

Comment: This leaves a too large gap between the two adjacent (non-hidded) sections though ...

Answer (score 0):

It for only constant cell

```
-(void)tableViewSearchPeopleCellHide:(BOOL)hide{

    searchCellShouldBeHidden=hide;
    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:1 inSection:0]];
    [self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:1 inSection:0] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];
    cell.hidden=hide;
    self.searchPeople.hidden=hide;//UILabel
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   // UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    if (searchCellShouldBeHidden) //BOOL saying cell should be hidden
        return 0.0;
    else
        return [super tableView:tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you can do is tag the cell from storyboard which you want to hide.
Put some standard number which you can identify.

Add this code.

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [super tableView:tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    if (cell.tag==10) { //I have put 10 for some static cell.       
                cell.hidden=YES;
                return 0;         

    }
     cell.hidden = NO;
    return [super tableView:tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the cell you want to hide to hidden somewhere in your code. Add this code: (If your cell has different row height, then you need to override more functions)

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    int rowCount=0;
    for ( int row=0; row<[super tableView:tableView numberOfRowsInSection:section]; ++row){
        NSIndexPath* path=[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:row inSection:section];
        UITableViewCell* cell=[super tableView:tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:path];
        if (!cell.hidden){
            ++rowCount;
        }
    }
    return rowCount;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    int realRow=-1;
    for ( int row=0; row<[super tableView:tableView numberOfRowsInSection:indexPath.section]; ++row){
        NSIndexPath* path=[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:row inSection:indexPath.section];
        UITableViewCell* cell=[super tableView:tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:path];
        if (!cell.hidden){
            ++realRow;
        }
        if (realRow==indexPath.row)
            return cell;
    }
    return nil;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Use index path to identify the cell in tableview height delegate and return 0**

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {

        if someCondition {

            if indexPath.row == 1 || indexPath.row == 2 || indexPath.row == 3 {
                return 0 
            }

        }else{

            if indexPath.row == 4 {
                return 0 
            }

        }


    return super.tableView(tableView, heightForRowAt: indexPath)
}
```